# Java android layout , buttons with two RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android

I want to create this :

[image]

I've written this code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF747B86"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapFrame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mapview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/about"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
                    android:paddingRight="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="6sp"
                    android:text="About"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <ZoomControls
                    android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dolny_pasek"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="#e2e2e2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pasek_szcz_maly"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
                android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
                android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
                android:paddingTop="5.0dip">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/street"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/street"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_prev"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_next"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_prev"
                            android:clickable="true">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/aktualneAutoText"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:paddingTop="2dip"
                                android:text="Pobieranie..."
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've a problem that I don't know how to put a button which will be in two RelativeLayout. I tried to add buttons which will be in RelativeLayout that contains maps and in RelativeLayout which is under first RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this in a Single Relative layout without too much nesting. Or you can do something like this:

```
RelativeLayout (matchparent width and height)
  LinearLayout (vertical, alignParentRight)
  LinearLayout (id=bottomControls, alignParentBottom, vertical)
    LinearLayout horizontal
    LinearLayout horizontal
  Button (alignParentBottom, marginBottom=bottomControls Height + half of this button's height)
  Button (alignParentBottom, marginBottom=bottomControls Height + half of this button's height)
```

Comment: Ok I will try do it

Comment: @PawełO don't forget to accept as Answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest trying this out in the Constraint Layout and see what your results are.

The layout allows for a flat hierarchy and is more memory efficient than deep nested layouts.

I'll give this a try too and get back to you.

Comment: Could you explain me how I Can do this ? Because I don't under stand you

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did this and is work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF747B86"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
            <!--<RelativeLayout-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="50dip"-->
            <!--android:background="#FF747B86">-->

            <!--<ImageButton-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/menu"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_centerVertical="true"-->
            <!--android:background="@android:color/transparent"-->
            <!--android:src="@drawable/menu"-->
            <!--android:textAlignment="center" />-->

            <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mapFrame"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
                        android:id="@+id/mapview"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/about"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
                        android:paddingRight="5sp"
                        android:paddingTop="6sp"
                        android:text="About"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <ZoomControls
                        android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/show_quick_menu"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageUp"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/lewe_menu_off"
                                android:clickable="true" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="2dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="#FF747B86">

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rel"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/lewe_menu_on"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/iv2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/iv1"
                                android:background="@color/background"
                                android:textAlignment="center" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/iv1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/iv2"
                                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv2"
                                android:background="@color/background"
                                android:textAlignment="center" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/iv3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/iv2"
                                android:background="@color/background"
                                android:textAlignment="center" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/iv4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/iv3"
                                android:background="@color/background"
                                android:textAlignment="center" />


                            <!--<ImageView-->
                            <!--android:id="@+id/clock"-->
                            <!--android:layout_width="30dp"-->
                            <!--android:layout_height="30dp"-->
                            <!--android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"-->
                            <!--android:layout_centerVertical="true"-->
                            <!--android:src="@drawable/ikona_zegar_18" />-->

                        </RelativeLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/dolny_pasek"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="#e2e2e2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/pasek_szcz_maly"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
                    android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
                    android:paddingTop="5.0dip">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/street"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/street"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_prev"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_next"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_prev"
                            android:clickable="true">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/aktualneAutoText"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:paddingTop="2dip"
                                android:text="Pobieranie..."
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/lin"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/aktualneAutoText">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/clock_image"
                                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ikona_zegar_18" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/timeText"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                    android:text="Czas"
                                    android:textAlignment="center"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"
                                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/curr_nr"
                                android:layout_width="200dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/lin"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/text"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>


                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_prev"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/street"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text="@string/less"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />


                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_next"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/street"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text="@string/greater"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/lin22"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/button_prev"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/szczegoly_ico3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/szczegoly_predkosc_ikona" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/szczegoly3"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                                    android:text="Auto"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                            </LinearLayout>


                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/szczegoly_ico1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/lin22">

                            <ListView
                                android:id="@+id/listViewProperties"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:clickable="false"
                                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                                android:visibility="visible" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/qick_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
            app:elevation="7dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/mapview"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
            app:elevation="7dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/mapview"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <!--<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/nav_view"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="left"-->
        <!--android:background="@drawable/logowanie_tlo"-->
        <!--android:fitsSystemWindows="true"-->
        <!--app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"-->
        <!--app:itemTextColor="#FFCDCED0"-->
        <!--app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```